# Templated operator=() and overload resolution

Tags: c++, gcc, overload-resolution, gcc11

Consider the [following code snippet](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4BOiBWVe1JOy4Gqb):

```
#include <utility>

struct test {
    template <class Other>
    test& operator=(Other&&);

    int& i_;
};


int main() {
    int i = 0;
    test t1{i}, t2{i};
    t1 = std::move(t2); // tries to select the implicitly-declared one!
}
```

When trying to compile with GCC11.1 (with `-std=c++2a`), it attempts to select the compiler-generated `operator=`, which is deleted, and fails. The previous GCC versions successfully build this code.

To my understanding, the implicitly-generated deleted `operator=` is not viable, so the operator template should be selected. Is it a GCC bug or am I missing something?

Comment: For me, it looks for `test& test::operator=<test>(test&&)` which is obviously templated one and it fails because it has no definition. If I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: @Afshin take a look at the error: "error: use of deleted function 'test& test::operator=(test&&)'".  The compiler doesn't care about the definition, as it may exist in another TU.

Comment: it gives me: 'undefined reference to `test& test::operator=<test>(test&&)`'. You can see it here: https://godbolt.org/z/1dTf58jfo

Comment: OH!!! it is ok for Gcc 11.2, but it gives error that you mentioned on GCC 11.1. it is probably a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bug. It looks for templated method on GCC 11.2 but as you mentioned, it sees deleted method on GCC 11.1.